# Weighted K-means with GPS Data

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, k-means

**OBJECTIVE**

- Aggregate store locations GPS information (longitude, latitude)
- Aggregate size of population in surrounding store area (e.g 1,000,000
  residents)
- Use K-means to determine optimal distribution centers,
  given store GPS data and local population (i.e distribution centers
  are located closer to urban stores vs. rural stores due to higher
  demand).

**ISSUES**

1. I've been [researching](http://cs.au.dk/~simina/weighted.pdf) on how to add weighted variables to a k-means algorithm, but am unsure on the *actual* process of weighting the variables. For example, if I have the [lat, long, and population (in thousands)] (e.g "New York" = `[40.713, 74.005, 8406]`) wouldn't this construct the centriod in 3-dimensional space? If so, wouldn't the distances be improperly skewed and mis-represent the best location for a warehouse distribution center?
2. Additional [research](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch8.pdf) alludes to UPGMA, "Unweighted Pair Group Method" where the size of the cluster is taken into account. However, I haven't fully reviewed this method and the intricacies associated with this method.

**REFERENCES**

Reference 1:  http://cs.au.dk/~simina/weighted.pdf (page 5)

> It can also be shown that a few other algorithms similar to k-means, namely k-median and k-mediods are also
>   weight-separable. The details appear in the appendix. Observe that all of these popular objective functions are highly
>   responsive to weight.

Reference 2: https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch8.pdf (page 39: "Ability to Handle Different cluster sizes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You only want to do k-means in the (longitude, latitude) space. If you add population as a 3rd dimension, you will bias your centroids towards the midpoint between large population centres, which are often far apart.

2) The simplest hack to incorporate a weighting in k-means is to repeat a point (longitude, latitude) according to its population weight.

3) k-means is probably not the best clustering algorithm for the job, as travel times do not scale linearly with distance. Also, you are basically guaranteed to never have a distribution centre bang in the middle of a large population centre, which is probably not what you want. I would use DBSCAN, for which scikit-learn has a nice implementation:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: For your point #2, wouldn't the dubplication of x,y coordinates (as a substitute for weight) have no affect on the centriod since the x,y points are "stacked and flattened" on a two dimensional plane, thus resembling a single, unweighted point? 

With regards to your point #3, it seems like DBscan might be a good candidate since density can be accounted for. More research required.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is that it depends on your data structure. If you keep track of your points (and multiples of a point where appropriate) in a list or an array then any k-means implementation (certainly the one in scikit-learn) will do the right thing, i.e. give that location more weight. If you store your points in a set, then duplications are discarded, in which case you would revert to the unweighted case.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! Answer accepted as it met the requirements of the original question.